# If 2 people have 2 days off per week each, what are the odds that they would have at least one day off that is the same?

Tags: probability

If 2 people have 2 days off per week each, what are the odds that they would have at least one day off that is the same?
How do you solve this? Any help?

Comment: What is the probability that all are different?

Comment: The probability of getting any combination of off days off is the same for the person. Ex.: (Monday/Tuesday's probability is the same as Tuesday/Sunday)

Comment: For each person, are the two days off consecutive?

Comment: No, they can be any combination of days

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  As a minimum you're expected to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom{7}{2}^2$ ways they can choose their days off. Of these, $\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}$ involve no overlap. Therefore, the probability of some overlap is $1-\dfrac{\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{7}{2}}=1-\dfrac{5\times 4}{7\times 6}=\dfrac{11}{21}$.

Comment: @Joffan I advise you to make that a separate question. That'll give you room to decide what counts as adjacent. For example, are the first & last days of the week adjacent?

Comment: I arrived to the same answer, but I was asking myself how to properly explain to my peers. I couldn't properly explain why you would use the (5|2) part? (sorry I can't format it properly)

Comment: @FilipeF. Because if you try to list the no-overlap combinations, each time you specify one person's days off only $5$ days are available for the second person to choose from.

Comment: @FilipeF. Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.